# Kohana 3 - Getting value from URL

Tags: routes, kohana, kohana-3

I have log in functionality that will check for a session, if it not there the user will be redirected via `Request::instance()->redirect('managers/error/1');`

In the error action in the managers controller I can't get the value 1 which represents a specific error msg.
How can I capture the value "1" from the url, I'm only using standard routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your route, you could do

```
public function action_error($id) {
   // $id will be your 1
}
```

Or you could set up a route explicitly

```
Route::set('managers_errors', 'managers/error/<id>',  array('id' => '\d+'));
```

Then you could use in the method / action

```
$id = $this->request->param('id');
```